# WebStorm does not detect android SDK

Tags: android, cordova, webstorm

I want to create a PhoneGap app that should run (also) on android later. In my run configurations I choose 'Platform: android'. I added the path to my 'android-sdk-macosx' to the directories (Add Content Root) and even marked it as a resource root which is certainly not necessary.

Anyway, WebStorm keeps saying 'Warning: Cannot detect android SDK in path'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

using homebrew with 'brew install android-sdk' fixes the problem. also necessary to add the new path variable as explained by brew. use the android-sdk manager to get the desired files with command 'android'.